# What besides a batch process/future call can update an opportunity on a schedule?

Tags: scheduled-job, asyncapexjob

We have this weird issue where certain opportunities are being updated around the same time each day, but I cannot figure out for the life of me how this is happening.  There are no batch processes/future calls that run during this time that update opportunities.  There are processes that add a chatter post to certain opportunities during this time, but I don't think that should update opps.

I have also checked the login history for the lastmodified user to ensure that there are no api logins during this time.

I have also checked to ensure no time-based workflow occurs on the opportunity.

Comment: You can add the user in the debug log and next day try to find out why it is happening

Comment: You list a few asynchronous processes but *not* `Schedulable`...

Comment: Rollup summaries on the Opp will cause it to be update if the records it rolls up is modified. Also, i believe certain chatter posts will also cause an update on the opp.